# How to Auto generate popup every 15mins using javascript

Tags: javascript, css, popup, colorbox

I have a small requirement in my website. An Auto Popup with image/video should be displayed in colorbox every 15 mins and remain for 30 secs and will close automatically.

Can anyone help with the Javascript?

Comment: Don't do that.  That's a great way to make users hate your site.

Comment: Apart from the previous comment, which is very true, we might be able to help if you show some effort, and tell us where you got stuck. E.g. did you even consider/investigate using timers?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) and [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout). Just replace the 1000 with 30000 (30 seconds) and the 1500 with 60000 * 15 (15 minutes). (Added some lower values for the demo.)

```js
function openPopup() {
    console.log('OPEN');
}

function closePopup() {
    console.log('CLOSE');
}

setInterval(function() {
    openPopup();
    setTimeout(function() {
        closePopup();
    }, 1000);
}, 1500);
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the function every 15 minutes. The function creates a new element which is then self-destructed by the same function after 30 secs.

```js
setInterval(function() {
  popUp()
}, 900000); // 900,000 = 15 mins * 60 secs * 1000 miliseconds

function popUp() {
  var popup = document.createElement('div');
  popup.id = "popup";
  popup.innerHTML = "the Video you want!";
  document.body.appendChild(popup);
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById('popup'))
  }, 30000); // 30000 = 30 secs * 1000 miliseconds
}
```

You need to style the popup according to your taste with css - probably with position:fixed